# How does visual studio resolve unicode string from different encoding source file ?

Tags: visual-studio, unicode, compilation

I know if I using unicode charset in vs, I can use `L"There is a string"` to present an unicode string. I think `There is a string` will be read from srouce file when vs is doing lexical parsing, it will decode `There is a string` to unicode from source file's encoding.

I have change source file to some different encodings, but I always got the correct unicode data from `L` marco. Dose vs detect the encoding of source file to covert `There is a string` to correct unicode ? If not, how does vs achieve this ?

I'm not sure whether this question could be asked in SO, if not , where should I ask? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What "different encodings" did you try? AFAIK, Files without a byte order mark character default to "ANSI" (the localized encoding...US Windows is cp1252, but it varies by locale), otherwise, the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character as the first codepoint in the file identifies one of the UTF encodings.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have tried GB2312, UTF-8. So vs will detect file encoding to covert unicode? Is there some file encoding vs do not support to do this transform?

Comment: What localized version of the OS are you using?  For Chinese, GB2312 might be the ANSI encoding.  I'd expect other localizations to fail or at least corrupt characters, because Windows doesn't add any indication of the encoding to the file and will assume current ANSI encoding.  UTF encoded-files, however, are written by VS to start with a BOM character that has a specific signature in different UTF encodings.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes I 'm using GB2312. So if I remove the `BOM`, it will fail to convert? GB2312 is ANSI, so I'm confused with how vs detect the encoding.

Comment: **Without** a BOM, VS assumes the ANSI encoding. So save something as UTF8, remove the first 3 bytes (EF BB BF) and the file will be interpreted as CP1252 on US Windows, but GB2312 on Chinese Windows.  VS won't detect the encoding. It will just assume one if no BOM is present.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I understand, I have tried save source file as UTF-8 without BOM, VS warned me that I have some characters can not be presented in current code page(936). So I think VS will assume the encoding is OS's local encoding if there is no BOM.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Plz post your comment as answer and I will accept you.

Comment: @MarkTolonen At last, I saved source code as UTF-8 without BOM, the Chinese string like `L"中文"` will be converted as GB2312, so the result unicode array will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS won't detect the encoding without a BOM<sup>1</sup> signature at the start of a source file. It will just assume the localized ANSI encoding if no BOM is present.

A BOM signature identifies the UTF8/16/32 encoding used. So if you save something as UTF-8 (VS will add a BOM) and remove the first 3 bytes (EF BB BF), then the file will be interpreted as CP1252 on US Windows, but GB2312 on Chinese Windows, etc.

You are on Chinese Windows, so either save as GB2312 (without BOM) or UTF8 (with BOM) for VS to decode your source code correctly.

<sup>1</sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark